# Lost all the blue icons on the world map

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

How do I get back all the blue icons on the world map for things like jobs, car races, missions or deathmatches?

Answer (score 4):

That was a feature came with GTA Online Freemode Update, 1.29.

1) Open "Interaction" Menu (press m on pc)

[image: Open interaction menu]

2) Open "Hide Options" Menu

[image: open hide options]

3) Open "Jobs" Menu

[image: open jobs menu]

4) Switch to custom mode

5) Set all jobs to "show"

Your blips must now be visible. If all aren't visible, repeat through the third step, but do it to "other" and "event" tabs

Comment: Also yes I know, my character is scary. It is near impossible to get a good character, so I went for the worst.

Comment: Thank you.  Got it all back now.   I appreciate the help

Comment: Hit the green check if this solved your issue!